# Pandas code runs on Python 3.6 (windows & osx) and not 3.5 (rasp pi3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, raspberry-pi3

I have a function running fine on python 3.6 in windows and osx, but I've put it on a raspberry pi3 running python 3.5 and now it returns an error.

Before I post the entire script, I'd just like to know if I'm missing something simple, or if it's got to get more complicated...

the code returning the error is:

`df = df.set_index(df.groupby('Timestamp').cumcount(), append=True)`

df contains multiple rows with the same timestamp (Timestamp is the index) which I'm using as the index.

The error exception string being returned is only `'Timestamp'`, so I'm not sure entirely what is wrong...

Here is the traceback. Not sure if this helps:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/media/pi/6144-7C57/Algodata/scripts/myfile.py", line 61, in myfunction
df_ask = df.set_index(df.groupby('Timestamp').cumcount(), append=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3991, in groupby
**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1511, in groupby
return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 370, in __init__
mutated=self.mutated)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2462, in _get_grouper
in_axis, name, gpr = True, gpr, obj[gpr]
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2059, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2066, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1386, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3543, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2136, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4433)
File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4279)
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13742)
File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13696)
KeyError: 'Timestamp'
```

Comment: Please post error verbatim. If long, usually last few lines.

Comment: @Parfait, does this update help?

Comment: It means you don't have a column named Timestamp in the version that raises the error. The root of your problem is probably somewhere else where the Timestamp column appear in one of them but does not appear in another one.

Comment: @ayhan, I don't understand how that would explain why it works fine in Python 3.6.5 on my mac and windows machines?

Comment: @ayhan, 'Timestamp' is the index. Preceding lines were: `df.set_index('Timestamp',inplace=True)`  # and
`df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first')]`